# Temporary table and SQL request

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to make a temporary table for a query but I do not see how to formulate it.

I have to create a temporary table containing for each customer and product, the
total quantity ordered from the product by the customer in all orders.

Here are the tables and the fields :

```
Customer (Nocust (PK), CTotMont, Nborder)
Product (Noprod (PK), Pxunit, Qtestk)
Order (Noorder (PK), Montorder, Nocust)
Line (Noorder (PK), Nordre (PK), Qteorder, Puacc, Noprod, Monttline)
```

> • Nocust is the customer number.
>
> • CtotMont indicates the amount spent by the customer (type:
>   smallmoney).
>
> • Nborder indicates the total number of orders made by a customer.
>
> • Noprod is the product number.
>
> • Pxunit indicates the unit price of a product (type: smallmoney).
>
> • Qtestk indicates the number of available items of a certain product.
>   This value must always be> 0.
>
> • Montorder indicates the amount of an order (type: smallmoney).
>
> • A number order Noorder consists of several lines numbered by Nordre
>
> • Qteorder indicates the number of items ordered.
>
> • Puacc indicates the unit price granted (not necessarily the unit
>   price, type smallmoney).
>
> • Montline is an attribute calculated by Puacc * Qteorder (as Puacc * Qteorder)

I try to start :

```
select Qteorder, Nocust, Noprod 
into #Qtetotale
from line 
join order on line.noorder=order.noorder 
group by Noprod, Nocust, Qteorder
```

Comment: What database engine are you using? Temp tables are created slightly differently depending on the rdbms system.

Comment: I use SQL Server

Comment: What is your question  here? You haven't even given a requirement. Have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Forum Etiquette: How to post  a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). Also, why a temporary table? These are, as they suggest, temporary, and are destroyed at the end of the session. Are you planning to do something with them afterwards?

Comment: Sorry for the presentation of my post. I want to create a temporary table containing for each customer and product, the total quantity ordered from the product by the customer in all orders.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. Have a look at the links I've provided; they explain how to create a well formatted question, and how to provide Consumable Sample data, and expected results, to compliment it.

Answer (score 0):

proceed as follow:

```
create table #Temp
(
    Qteorder int, 
    Nocust Varchar(50), 
    Noprod Varchar(50), 
)

;WITH all_items
AS (
select Qteorder, Nocust, Noprod 
from line 
join order on line.noorder=order.noorder 
group by Noprod, Nocli, Qtecom
) 

Insert Into #Temp
Select Qteorder,Nocust ,Noprod  from all_items
```

When done, don't forget to drop the temp table

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp
End
```

Comment: when I execute the query nothing is displayed in the table

Comment: @Roxanne have u created the temp table and after that execute the CTE followed by the Insert into ? and execute a     Select * from all_items

Comment: I have a syntax error to the with clause but the problem is the query because I'm not sure it's correct

Comment: @Roxanne Are you using the Sql Server or something else ?   also do you execute all thing at once or the temp table first then the ;with statement and the insert ? just give more details on how you proceed so I could help

Comment: Thanks for your help. I start to create the table #temp and then I execute the ;with statement but I have a syntax error

Comment: remove the group by statement 

;WITH all_items
AS (
select Qteorder, Nocust, Noprod 
from line 
join order on line.noorder=order.noorder 
)

Comment: I have always a syntax error even withtout the group by statement

Comment: I'm going to assume that you've chosed for your CTE a particular name that not already belongs 
to an existing table. therefore I was able to reporoduce the same error on my computer once 
I execute the query for creating the temp table the execute the CTE **ALONE Without the insert into 
statement.**, try to run the whole query the create table,CTE, and the insert into( Select the code 
and execute it **DO NOT RUN THE PART FOR DROPPING THE TABLE **

Comment: i do not have a problem creating the table it works but i have a problem with the with clause

Comment: I know it's because you execute the with clause alone you should execute it with the Insert statement

Answer (score -1):

In SQL Server there are two types of temporary tables which are stored in tempdb system database.

1. Local temp table : accessible within the connection

   Syntax: `CREATE TABLE #tablename(column datatype,column1 datatype,...)`
2. Global temp table : can be accessed across all connections while the base connection is active

   Syntax: `CREATE TABLE ##tablename(column datatype,column1 datatype,...)`

Comment: Pointless comment.